# Restarting from the beginning using do while loops

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a small block of code where it just runs through using functions.  Im trying to figure out how to create a function at the end to where it asks the user if they want to continue.  if they type Y then it starts back at the beginning.  if the user types N then it the code ends.  it looks something like this:

```
int main() {
//functions running
} while (startOver);
```

so im trying to put a function at startOver that if the user types in Y then it will start back over.  Im confused at where to go from here.

Comment: You need to put a `while` *inside* a function. You can't just slap it on the end. Consider writing a `getInput()` function and a dispatcher to run the appropriate chunk of code, like a `switch` statement or a lookup table.

Answer (score 3):

This is a skeleton to get you started:

```
/* Prompts the user if program should continue
 * blocking
 * return true if it the program should continue, false if it should stop
 */
bool should_continue_ask_user();

int main()
{
    do
    {
        // functions running
    } while (should_continue_ask_user());
}
```